# jQuery | cannot add click event from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Description

I want to remove an onclick attribute from a element and instead bind it's function to it's click event.

```js
$("[onclick]").each(function() {
  //Entfernt normales Event
  $(this).off("click");  
  //bindet altes Event
  try {
      $(this).on( "click", $(this).attr("onclick"));
      document.write('successly freed onclick');
  } catch(e) {
      document.write('failed');
      console.warn(e);
      $("[error]").val(e);
  }
  //Entfernt attribut (cosmetic)
  $(this).removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

```css
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: dimgray;
  font-family: monospace;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  border: red 2px solid;
  resize: none;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alert('beep')">Boo</button>
<textarea error></textarea>
```

but this fails.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string x

Can somebody help me with this?

Link to test case

https://codepen.io/Blubbll/pen/aYZQjg

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Might want to explain a little better, because the code makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: i wanted to unbind the click event from an element (set via the onclick attribute)and make it a event handled by javascript itself. but jQuery didn't like it. prop helped me here i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `prop('onclick')` instead of `attr` since `attr` will return a simple string. jQuery was trying to make the string `alert('beep')` in to a function to assign it to the click and resulted in some error in jQuery.

> [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.
>
> [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

```js
$("[onclick]").each(function() {
  //Entfernt normales Event
  $(this).off("click");  
  //bindet altes Event
  try {
  console.log($(this).prop("onclick"));
    $(this).on( "click", $(this).prop("onclick"));
    document.write('successly freed onclick');
  }
  catch(e) {
    document.write('failed');
    console.warn(e);
    $("[error]").val(e);
  }
  $(this).removeAttr("onclick")
});
```

```css
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: dimgray;
  font-family: monospace;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  border: red 2px solid;
  resize: none;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alert('beep')">Boo</button>
<textarea error>
</textarea>
```